# How can I create a directory for each category under _posts in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to have such a structure in my Jekyll site:

`_posts
    php
        2014-10-31-this-is-a-test.md
    ruby
        2014-12-01-some-other-test.md`

I would like all posts in the `php` directory to be in the `PHP` category, and all posts in `ruby` to be in the `Ruby` category. Here is my `_config.yml` file:

`defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: post
      comments: true
      share: true
  -
    scope:
      path: "_posts/php"
      type: "posts"
    values:
      category: PHP
  -
    scope:
      path: "_posts/ruby"
      type: "posts"
    values:
      category: Ruby`

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path: "php"` or `path: "ruby"` sets the category.

Note: [any category set in the front matter will replace the one in default config](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#precedence).